# How to implement Eltwise layer in pyCaffe

Tags: python, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I am trying to implement the Eltwise layer in PyCaffe to sum 2 inputs.

My goal is to get this in prototext:

```
layer {
  name: "eltwise_sum"
  type: "Eltwise"
  bottom: "v1"
  bottom: "v2"
  top: "v1_v2_sum"
  eltwise_param { operation: SUM }
}
```

I couldn't find any documentation or even google examples on how to do this in PyCaffe.

```
net.v1_v2_sum = caffe.layers.Eltwise( net.v1, 
                                      net.v2, 
                                      name='eltwise_sum', 
                                      param ={'operation': 'SUM'}
                                    )
```

However, I keep getting an error. I suspect this is due to not specifying the sum operation correctly, but I cant find any documentation on how to do this right?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in [caffe.proto](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto). Each parameter that you include in a layer is listed in that file. For [`Eltwise`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/306672023ea79f0755e92ca345bc70c068a91cc4/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L713) layer, the parameters are `operation`, `coeff`, `stable_prod_grad`. The parameter `operation` takes 3 values `0`, `1` or `2` whose mappings are defined by an `enum EltwiseOp`. As far as the parameter `name` is concerned, you will find it in [`LayerParameter`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/306672023ea79f0755e92ca345bc70c068a91cc4/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L326). I couldn't find any documentation on this. It's just something you learn along the way. I hope this clears your doubts.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful! I wish they'd make it easier to find this though ...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so apparently there is an integer corresponding to each operation Eltwise performs, and 1 corresponds to sum, so the correct implementation is:

```
net.v1_v2_sum = caffe.layers.Eltwise( net.v1, 
                                      net.v2, 
                                      name='eltwise_sum', 
                                      operation = 1
                                    )
```

I figured this out by trial-and-error. See Parag S. Chandakkar's answer for more info on how to understand this from their git code.